# Can I declare a local variable that directly modifies a class field

Tags: c#, dictionary, timer

So, I have a class that has a `Dictionary<string,System.Timers.Timer>` called "**timers**" and I have a method in the class that accesses the "**timers**" field:

```
public static void Save(FastColoredTextBox editor) //this works fine
{
    timers[(string)editor.Tag].Dispose();

    timers[(string)editor.Tag] = new Timer(Timeout*1000) { AutoReset = false };
    timers[(string)editor.Tag].Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    timers[(string)editor.Tag].Start();
}
```

As you can see, I use `timers[(string)editor.Tag]`, because when I set a variable like this:

```
public static void Save(FastColoredTextBox editor) //doesn't modify the Dictionary
{
    var timer = timers[(string) editor.Tag];
    timer.Dispose();

    timer = new Timer(Timeout*1000) { AutoReset = false };
    timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    timer.Start();
}
```

"**timer**" is declared as a local variable, and doesn't modify the `Dictionary`.

So, can I set a local variable like the "**timer**" in the second example that will modify the class field `Dictionary`, or will I have to use the direct access method like in the first example?

Comment: C# doesn't have global variables. You can have a static field, but it will need to be part of some type.

Comment: take a look at Property's or auto properties..also do a google search and read up on `Scope` and understand which takes precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a hybrid approach:

```
string tag = (string)editor.Tag;
timers[tag].Dispose();

var timer = new Timer(Timeout*1000) { AutoReset = false };
timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
timer.Start();

timers[tag] = timer;
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thanks!